# Compare last_modified to date.today() in Django

Tags: python, django

In models.py

```
class PapaAbb(models.Model):
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def is_new(self):
        if self.last_modified == date.today():
            return True
        return False
```

and call this in HTML template as

```
{% if papaabb.is_new %}new{% endif %}
```

I expected showing 'new' text on html page but nothing happened.
Any advice would be welcome.
thx in advance...

Comment: hi i think you made a mistake in the field you write DateTimeFilel instead of DateTimeField:last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

Comment: Thx, I misspell that code. I did correctly in coding file but it doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried  the result below?

Comment: Yes, It worked!!! I just waited 6 minutes to enter 'accept' button.

Comment: Amazing,happy coding guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im guessing its because `last_modified` is a datetime. Try:

```
if self.last_modified.date() == date.today():
```